# How can I set the permissions of a file directory so that only a specific Java program can alter the directory?

Tags: java, security, unix, file-permissions

I've built a Java program with an administrator console and a server thread. The server will be communicating with remote clients who are sending encrypted information. That information is being written by the server into a directory. Administrators, through the admin console, will log in, verify that they are an admin, and will be able to send commands to the server to alter the directory. Is there a way assure that only the Java program and superuser are capable of reading, writing, or executing the files in that directory? If not, how can I be sure that an adversary does not alter the program themselves?

Comment: create separate user and give access only to this user, of course java app should be run under it too

Comment: wouldn't this separate user have to stay logged in for as long as I want the adminconsole and server to be up? and if so, then how does this mitigate the risk of an adversary with physical access to the computer? the special user is still logged in. the adversary can just close the program and alter the files on the unix level.

Comment: you can run app as "unlogged" user

Comment: can you elaborate on this?

Comment: you can execute any app under the different users, see `sudo -u` option

Comment: If an adversary has physical access to the computer, game over.